# MongoDB - update specific array element by id

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I`ve been trying these since yesterday but I couldn`t make it.

I have 2 different Schemas, the User Schema and the Vital Signs Schema. The Vital Signs Schema is inside the userSchema as an array. What i need to do is to edit an specific vitalSigns object with an unique Id

Here is a postman example of the info i need to update

[image: 1]

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email:{type: String, required: true},
    password:[{type: String, required: true}],
    confirmPassword:[{type: String, required: true}],
    personalData: personalDataSchema,
    vitalSigns: [vitalSignsSchema],
})
```

```
const vitalSignsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    systolic: { type: 'Number', required: false },
    diastolic: { type: 'Number', required: false },
    temperature: { type: 'Number', required: false },
    pulse: { type: 'Number', required: false },
    rate: { type: 'Number', required: false },
    blood: { type: 'Number', required: false },
    date: { type: 'Date', required: false },
})
```

My route is catching both userId and vitalSigns because i tried to make it work with a lot of ways but i couldn't

```
Router.post('/user/:userId/vitalSignsEdit/:vitalId', async (req, res) => {
    
    userServices.editVitalSigns(req.params.userId,req.params.vitalId, req.body)


})
```

Here is one example of a way that I tried to use to make it work but instead of updating the specific vitalSigns Id, it created another object of vitalSigns with the same Id that i tried to change.

```
  User.findById(userId)
  .then( user => {
    if(user) {
      if(user.vitalSigns.find( e => e._id === data._id)) {
        User.updateOne({_id: userId}, { vitalSigns: [...user.vitalSigns, data] })
        .then(e => console.log(e), i => console.log(i))
      }
    }
  })
```

Hope someone could help me with these.

Comment: Please [edit] to paste the text used in the image into your question so that it can be read on all devices, quoted, edited, and found through search. As it stands now, [your image makes it hard to answer your question or for people with related issues to find your question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). See the [formatting documentation](/editing-help) for tips to make your text appear nicely without resorting to images.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `$push`

```
 User.updateOne({_id: userId}, { $push: { vitalSigns: data } })
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've already tried to do this but it didn't work. I think the problem of that is that you are targeting the user id but not the vitalSigns id.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$` to access the array element matched.

```js
db.collection.update({
  "vitalSigns._id": "vs1"
},
{
  $set: {
    "vitalSigns.$.modified": true
  }
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GfsDIGvJW0C)